# Program win32 installer from scratch

Tags: java, windows, installation, pseudocode

I want to recreate a basic Windows installer, like the ones nullsoft or innosetup produce, but in Java.
Unfortunatly, I'm a bit lost for some points.

First of all I'd have to copy the software data to `Program Files`, this point seems clear to me. But I suppose that I would also have to send some information to the OS, for instance to have my program's uninstaller listed in the `Programs and Features` part of the `Control Panel`.

And I also need to create some icons on the desktop and put an entry on start menu.

There are probably a ton of other things I forgot, so what are they, and what is the best way to do these in java ?

Comment: It looks to me like you are thinking about mimicking a win32 installer rather than programming one. I believe sane approach would be to use a binding API such as JNA and call actual Windows API functions from within Java. https://github.com/twall/jna

Comment: It can be a solution, but my "pseudoinstaller" has to run on both Windows and Linux, and even if ofc I will do an OS detection, and then execute the right code according to the right OS, will the jar execute on these two plateforms ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? Do you know that there are several such cross-platform  implementations written in java for years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [IzPack](http://izpack.org), I think is what you are looking for ...
If you don't like it as it is, you can take a look at the source code at the [official git repo](http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=izpack.git).

Comment: Nope that's not what I want. I just want to reproduce an installer with java, not pack my own app in an installer

Comment: Do you want to do this as an exercise or as a software product?

Comment: As an exercice, ofc ^^

Comment: @LoveMetal take a look at the source code of izpack, you will find inside useful information for your project ...